# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PHP 8.1

Tags: php

I updated the site from the old version to 8.0 and started giving this error referring to this code.

```
$exis = selectOne('users',['mail' => $email]);
            if($exis['mail'] === $email) {
            $errMsg = 'Пользователь с такой почтой уже зарегистрировался!';
        }else{
```

here is the selectOne function that I use

```
function selectOne($table, $params =[]){
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if(!empty($params)){
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($params as $key => $value){
            if(!is_numeric($value)){
                $value = "'".$value."'";
            }
            if($i===0){
                $sql = $sql." where $key=$value";
            }else{
                $sql=$sql."and $key=$value";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetch();
}
```

What is the fix for PHP 8.1 ?

I tried to find an answer to this question, but nothing helped, can you tell me how to fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In addition - what exactly is the error message you are getting?

Comment: This code is seriously vulnerable to SQL injection. Start parameterising your queries.

Comment: Anyway, regarding the error, what debugging have you done? `$query->fetch()` can return `false` (as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) if it fails, or there are no more rows. `false` is a boolean. Your function returns the result of fetch(), and `$exis = selectOne(...` puts that result into `$exis`. You then write `if($exis['mail'] === $email)`, which assumes that `$exis` is always an array. Therefore your error is because you're trying to use `$exis['mail']` in a case where `$exis` is actually `false`.

Comment: Probably this was just giving you a warning in older PHP, but in PHP 8 that's considered a bad piece of code (because its behaviour is not predictable) and now you get an error. You need to fix it by testing whether `$exis` is actually an array before trying to use it like one.